# How to add an assetic asset programmatically

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I need to add asset definitions to assetic "on the fly" because the location of the assets depends on configuration parameter values.

I've found the assetic.asset service tag which looks promising.
That tag is used in

```
vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AssetFactoryPass.php
```

What I have not been able to discover so far is what to put in my service class.

Comment: what you mean under "on th fly"? you want to be able change asset url in your templates or you talking about  `inputs:` block from assetic configuration ?

Comment: The actual asset to be loaded depends on a bundle configuration parameter. That parameter is not available in config.yml. I want to create a new asset and hand it to the asset manager during cache:clear and assetic:dump.

Comment: I know it has been more than a year but did you find the solution? I need exactly the same thing.

Comment: No. I never did find a reasonable answer. I stopped using Assetic and am now working with various tools like gulp. -- Good luck!!